# Visualize a snowflake space

Tags: metric-spaces

> **Definition.** Let $\varepsilon \in (0;1)$. The $\varepsilon$-snowflake of a metric space $(X,d)$ is the metric space $(X,d^\varepsilon)$, with the induced metric $d^\varepsilon(a,b) := d(a,b)^\varepsilon$ for all $a,b \in X$.

Consider the unit interval $X = [0;1]$ for $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ with the standard metric
$$
d: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}_+, \\
(a,b) \mapsto d(a,b) := |a-b|.
$$
Then, $(X,d^\varepsilon)$ is a snowflake with the metric $d^\varepsilon(a,b) = |a-b|^\frac{1}{2}$.

**My question:**
Is there a way to visualize $(X,d^\varepsilon)$ in this example? (like something you could draw on a blackboard...)

Comment: Do you know the reason for the name? This will help you with the visualization.

Comment: From the name, I would suspect an appearance like the Koch snowflake (or a similar fractal-like shape). But to draw it for concrete values (i.e. $\varepsilon=1/2$) is something my brain seems to have difficulties with ... :)  Maybe for a little context: I am taking a seminar course at university where we are about to look at Assouad's Embedding Theorem next week.